# Using FFMpeg to strip out PCM audio track from difficult AVI file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, avi

I have an AVI video file which has an audio channel and I want to use FFMpeg (v n4.3.1) to save that audio out to a wav file. For other similar tasks I have found that this command works:

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.avi -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22000 -y -ac 2 audiofile.wav
```

However, for the current file, Ffmpeg returns this error

[image: FFmpeg output]

The file does have audio. VLC can play the audio and MediaInfo shows this:

[image: Mediainfo data]

Oddly, when I tried an older version of FFMpeg (from April 2013) that worked and saved the audio.

I'd prefer to use the latest ffmpeg. Maybe I need to change the commandline params I'm using?

--edit: whole ffmpeg output --

```
ffmpeg version n4.3.1-ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  
built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  
configuration: --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-version=ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=/home/runner/work/ffmpeg-windows-builds/ffmpeg-windows-builds/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32- --enable-libcaca --enable-gray --enable-libtesseract --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libwebp --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenh264 --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvmaf --enable-libsrt --enable-libaribb24 --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2 --enable-opengl --enable-libdav1d --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libaom --enable-libvpx --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --extra-libs=-lharfbuzz --extra-libs=-lm --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DMODPLUG_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DCACA_STATIC --enable-amf --enable-libmfx --enable-gpl --enable-frei0r --enable-filter=frei0r --enable-librubberband --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxavs --enable-avresample --extra-cflags='-mtune=generic' --extra-cflags=-O3 --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/home/runner/work/ffmpeg-windows-builds/ffmpeg-windows-builds/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32
  
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100

[avi @ 00000133ff187cc0] sample size (1) != block align (4)

[avi @ 00000133ff187cc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 3942 kb/s): unspecified pixel format

Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo

Input #0, avi, from 'Rec1_0001.avi':
  
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 3942 kb/s, 24.99 fps, 24.99 tbr, 24.99 tbn, 24.99 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Output #0, wav, to 'Rec1_0001.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22000 Hz, stereo, s16, 704 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s16le
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the complete text output from ffmpeg instead of making an image of just some of the text.

Comment: I've added that now @llogan

Comment: Download a newer ffmpeg from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ (ffmpeg-git-essentials.7z) and try again.

Comment: Same result. Full output here: https://pastebin.com/3qzaXDhp

Comment: Consider increasing the value for the `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` options, such as `ffmpeg -y -probesize 15M -analyzeduration 15000000 -i input.avi -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22000 -ac 2 audiofile.wav` (increase the values if it doesn't work).

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything ( also tried larger numbers): https://pastebin.com/NRsxcAxz

Comment: I'll check with the person who gave me the file. Can I send it to you directly somehow? I'd prefer not to post the link publicly for now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with ffmpeg and I have now made a ticket on the ffmpeg trac. Thanks to @llogan for your help with this.